# How can I find the version of a toolbox used in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I am using QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton on Xubuntu. The QGIS-install comes with several default toolboxes. Orfeo Toolbox for image analysis is one of them. How can I find out which version of the Orfeo toolbox, or any other toolbox for that matter, is being used with my particular QGIS installation?

Comment: I found my Orfeo Toolbox version here (C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing\algs\otb\maintenance\OTBHelper.py) and editing the file. It would be great if there's a python command which could output all toolbox versions in the console.

Comment: Joseph, that file (OTBHelper.py) does not exist in my install on Ubuntu. Not in capitals, nor in small letters.

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. Hopefully others can advise on this as I'm sure it would be a useful feature to have for all platforms.

Comment: It does not exist in the standalone version of QGIS on windows either, unless you have updated the plugin. I guess the version is just that of the python file, and not of the otb algs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed QGIS via ubuntugis-unstable, you can as well add the latest otb packages from version 4.2.0 for trusty:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty

Once you have the Orfeo toolbox installed, open a command window and enter:

`/usr/bin/otbcli_QuickLook`

You will get an error message about missing parameters:

```
ERROR: Waiting for at least one parameter...
This is the Quicklook application, version 4.2.0
Generates a subsampled version of an image extract
```

The same works under Windows in the OSGEO4W shell:

`otbcli_quicklook` will give you the current version 4.2.1

Note that QGIS standalone under Windows will install OTB, while with OSGEO4W and ubuntugis you have to select it manually. The processing toolbox is just an interface to OTB, it does **NOT** contain the modules themselves (the same applies to GRASS, SAGA and R).

Comment: I think this answer is going the right way. There obviously are discrepancies which should be handled. In my install (qgis on xubuntu) I can not find the mentioned file. It might be that my install is not working. I will try to reinstall the package and then follow your procedure.

Comment: If you can not find the file, you have no **otb** installed on your system. It is not installed by the **qgis** packages!